# Clipping Bezier Tool lines with Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to cut/clip two parallel bezier lines with Inkscape using a triangle also made with the bezier tool and these are my steps.

- First draw a single straight line.
- Then do path > stroke to path on it
- Duplicate it and drag it below the first
- Select both lines and then select path > union
- Draw a triangle around the section that I want
- Do path > stroke to path on the triangle
- Select the two lines and the triangle and do object > clip > set clip

I was thinking that this would cut off the part of the lines that is outside of the triangle such that only the segments that are inside the triangle remain, however that is not what happens.  Everything disappears ... and if I turn on fill and stroke paint ... what's left looks like the intersection of the triangle and the lines ...

Thoughts?

Comment: I think the 2nd stroke-to-path is the problem. Remove that step.

Comment: AH!!  YES!!  Good Hunch!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Also the first steps where you are creating a path, doing stroke to path, and union are not necessary either.  You could simply draw a path, duplicate it, move it, and group them.  Clipping works on groups too!

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks for the heads up!!